# Property 'displayName' does not exist on type '() => any'

Tags: angular

I am seeing the following error, on my angular2 component upon compiling/building

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Params } from '@angular/router';
import {QueuedService} from '../queued.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reservation',
  templateUrl: './reservation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reservation.component.css']
})
export class ReservationComponent implements OnInit {
  username: string;
  useremail: string;
  route$: Router;
  queued$: QueuedService;
  constructor(route: Router, queued: QueuedService) {
    this.queued$ = queued;
    this.route$ = route;
    this.queued$.getUserInfo()
      .subscribe(
        result => {
            this.username = result.displayName;
            this.useremail = result.emails[0].value;
        }
      );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The error is the following

```
Property 'displayName' does not exist on type '() => any'.
Property 'emails' does not exist on type '() => any'.
```

I am unable to figure what the issue is?

**EDIT**
My getUserInfo function

```
  getUserInfo() {
    return this.http.get( this.host + '/auth/userdata')
    .map(response => response.json());
  }
```

Comment: What does your `getUserInfo()` method looks like?

Comment: @echonax edited the question

Comment: Can you try `(result) => {` and `(result: any) => {`?

Comment: What is the json data you are getting back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result is of type any, just change those two variables to type of any,

```
username: any;
useremail: any;
```

**EDIT**

Add a type of any to your result,

```
 this.queued$.getUserInfo()
      .subscribe(
        (result: any) => {
            this.username = result.displayName;
            this.useremail = result.emails[0].value;
        }
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

`getUserInfo()` doesn't declare a return type that has those properties. I suggest you do the sub action within `getUserInfo()` itself so that you don't cross any function boundaries with untyped objects.